# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined??Why?

Tags: javascript, redux

My native language is not English. So, I try my best to express problem clearly!
I want to use store.dispatch, So I do this (import { store } from "../index";)

index.js

```js
import reducers from "./reducer";
 
const store = createStore(reducers, compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.devToolsExtension?window.devToolsExtension():f =>f
) )
```

reducer.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { user  } from "./redux/user.redux";

 
export default combineReducers({
    user
})
```

user.js

```js
import axios from "axios"

import { store } from "../index";

const dispatch = store.dispatch;
export function register ({user, pwd, repeatpwd, type }) {
  
    axios.post("/user/info", {user, pwd, type}).then ( (res) => {
        if (res.status == 200 && res.data.isAuth === 0) {
           dispatch( registerSuccess({user, pwd, type}))
        } else {
           dispatch( errorMsg(res.data.msg));
        }
    })
}
```

Why store is undefined?
The path is right.

Comment: You haven't exported anything from `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

In order to have variable or module accessible in another module, you have to properly export it.

As you use ES6 standard `import/export` keywords, you have two ways of exporting context from one module to another:

- `export default` - you can export only one thing in one module like that and it will be represented in another import as a namespace. It is imported by providing path and naming it arbitrarily (you can name imported variable however you want)
- named export: `export variable` that allows for exporting multiple variables from one file. It is imported by providing exact variable name from the other module in curly brackets (or by importing everything). If you want to change the variable name, you have to alias it.

Both export types might co-exist, e.g. you may use `default` export for the main element in your file and `named exports` for smaller elements.

Example of default export:

```
// index.js
export default createStore({/.../});

// user.js
import store from '../index';
// store will be available here
```

Example of named export (that's what you probably seek, provided your `user.js` code):

```
// index.js - notice the difference!
export const store = createStore({/.../});

// user.js - notice the brackets!
import { store } from '../index';
// store will be available here
```

As it may be a bit confusing if you begin your frontend adventure, I **highly** recommend to read that article - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export